# ¿Tiene que ver algo con el buffer que no me muestre correctamente los números almacenados inicialmente?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, ordenamiento

Este es un ejercicio el cuál solicita en primer luego el número de elementos de un arreglo y luego pide el valor de cada elemento por consola. Luego mediante el método burbuja, que es un algoritmo de ordenamiento, organizo los números de menor a mayor. Luego imprimo los elementos del arreglo de menor a mayor pero ahí es cuando me muestra datos que no corresponden a los datos que inicialmente introduje. Tengo sospechas de que puede referirse al buffer y que necesito vaciarlo; mas no sé donde hacerlo. Quizás también se refiera a otro problema que no me he percatado. Lo que sé es que sí he investigado pero pocos resultados he encontrado y quisiera algún consejo. Utilicé Dev C++ como IDE.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    /*1. Vamos a pedir el número de datos*/
    int amount,i,j,aux;
    cout<<"Establezca el numero de datos: ";
    cin>>amount;
    
    
    /*2. Vamos a establecer los números almacenados en un arreglo*/ 
    int array[50];
    
    cout<<"INTRODUZCA LOS DATOS: "<<endl;
    for(i=0; i<amount; i++){
        cout<<"DATO #"<<i + 1<<" : ";
        cin>>array[i];111
    }
    
    
    /*3. Utilizaremos el algoritmo de ordenamiento: Método burbuja*/
    for(i=0;i<amount;i++){
        for(j=0;j<amount;j++){
            if(array[j]>array[j+1]){
                aux=array[j];
                array[j]=array[j+1];
                array[j+1]=aux;
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    /*4. Mostramos en pantalla el resultado final del arreglo*/
    cout<<endl<<"DATOS ORDENADOS: "<<endl;
    for(i = 0; i<amount; i++){
        cout<<"DATO #"<<i + 1<<" : "<<array[i]<<endl;
    }
    
    
    /*5. Mostramos el mayor y menor dato*/
    cout<<"MENOR DATO: "<<array[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"MAYOR  DATO: "<<array[amount];
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si para pedir los datos no llegas al límite, sino que paras uno antes:

```
cout<<"INTRODUZCA LOS DATOS: "<<endl;
    for(i=0; i<amount; i++){ // No llegas a 'amount', paras 1 antes
```

Luego, en tu bucle interno, vuelves a hacer los mismo ... pero luego accedes al indice + 1; con lo cual te estás pasando del límite:

```
for(j=0;j<amount;j++){
    if(array[j]>array[j+1]){
```

Debería ser

```
for(j=0;j<(amount-1);j++){
    if(array[j]>array[j+1]){
```

Y al final, al mostrar, tienes el mismo problema:

```
/*5. Mostramos el mayor y menor dato*/
cout<<"MENOR DATO: "<<array[0]<<endl;
cout<<"MAYOR  DATO: "<<array[amount]; // <-- fuera del límite
```

Debería ser

```
/*5. Mostramos el mayor y menor dato*/
cout<<"MENOR DATO: "<<array[0]<<endl;
cout<<"MAYOR  DATO: "<<array[amount-1];
```

Comment: Mil gracias, ya entendí cuál era mi error, espero tengas buen día.